# error "type 'task' has no subscript members" in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

We are working on a project for code and we are getting this error. This is the exact code we told to use however we always get an error. I'm not really sure how to resolve this. For the line that says `var tasks = task ()[]` it keeps saying that "type 'task' has no subscript members". How can we fix this?

```
import UIKit

var taskMgr: TaskManager = TaskManager ()

struct task {
    var name = "Unnamed"
    var desc = "Undescribed"
}

class TaskManager: NSObject {

   var tasks = task ()[]

   func addTask(name: String, desc: String) {
       self.tasks(task (name: name, desc: desc))!
   }

}
```

Comment: There are different versions of Swift. What you were told may work for a different version. But probably not. Check very, very carefully what you are typing.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error message is quite self-explanatory, it means "You try to access something on `task` via a subscript" ([more on subscripts here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html))

I guess that you intention is to initialize `tasks` with an empty list there, so you most probably meant something like this:

```
var tasks: [task] = []
```

Also note that you have a syntax error on `addTask` function. The correct one would be something like this:

```
self.tasks.append(task(name: name, desc: desc))
```

Finally, note that [type names are UpperCamelCased by convention](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82), so `Task` would be a more appropriate name.

I hope that this makes sense...